# Google Code Prettify with Markdown is not working

Tags: php, javascript, markdown, google-code-prettify

[Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) is working fine, but when I am using the Markdown content and show the content from the database, Prettify isn't working properly ([link of live result](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=7)).

This is what I am doing:

- Getting content with

  `<textarea name="article_content" id="wmd-input" class="wmd-panel"></textarea>`
- Then store output after (I am using [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community))

  `Markdown($_POST['article_content'])`

But in the result, the part I wrote in the code section is working fine if I don't use Markdown, but when I get the content from the textarea and use Markdown, it's not working.

Comment: any help/advice would be appreciated

Comment: The link with the example code is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.brightmeup.info."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the HTML code. You missed the class="prettyprint" off the *pre* tag.

```
<pre><code>try {
    $db-&gt;beginTransaction();

    $db-&gt;exec("SOME QUERY");

    $stmt = $db-&gt;prepare("SOME OTHER QUERY?");
    $stmt-&gt;execute(array($value));

    $stmt = $db-&gt;prepare("YET ANOTHER QUERY??");
    $stmt-&gt;execute(array($value2, $value3));

    $db-&gt;commit();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    //Something went wrong rollback!
    $db-&gt;rollBack();
    echo $ex-&gt;getMessage();
}
</code></pre>
```

should be

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><code>try {
    $db-&gt;beginTransaction();

    $db-&gt;exec("SOME QUERY");

    $stmt = $db-&gt;prepare("SOME OTHER QUERY?");
    $stmt-&gt;execute(array($value));

    $stmt = $db-&gt;prepare("YET ANOTHER QUERY??");
    $stmt-&gt;execute(array($value2, $value3));

    $db-&gt;commit();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    //Something went wrong rollback!
    $db-&gt;rollBack();
    echo $ex-&gt;getMessage();
}
</code></pre>
```

To fix the problem of having `<pre>` auto generated, you can try this:

```
$newcontent = str_replace('<pre>', '<pre class="prettyprint">', $_POST['article_content']);
```

Comment: love you buddy its working but where i need to add this in wmd js since it add the `<pre><code>` automatically

Comment: Add the class using javascript after the tags have been added? You can always add a wrapper tag and put the class on that (but not sure if prettyprint was done on pre.prettyprint or .prettyprint so you will have to try it and see).

Comment: could you add this `$cont =   $_POST['article_content'];
         $newcontent= (str_replace( '<pre>', '<pre class="prettyprint">',$cont));` in answer so i can accept your answer

Comment: Is the example code actually formatted correctly? Is "&gt;" literal? If it is, can you [explain it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13541174/edit) in your answer? And if not, format it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

For auto generated `<pre>` you can also use:

```
$('pre').addClass('prettyprint');
```